# Can't Get Clean Vagrant Box "Remove" or "Destroy"

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

I'm using Vagrant 1.8.1 on Windows 10.  When trying to remove or destroy a box, I got these contradictory results:

```
baria@DESKTOP-057K4L5 /c/repos/hub/vtc/linphone-windows-dependencies
$ vagrant box list
hashicorp/precise64  (virtualbox, 1.1.0)
windows_2012_r2_core (virtualbox, 0)

baria@DESKTOP-057K4L5 /c/repos/hub/vtc/linphone-windows-dependencies
$ vagrant box remove windows_2012_r2_core
Box 'windows_2012_r2_core' (v0) with provider 'virtualbox' appears
to still be in use by at least one Vagrant environment. Removing
the box could corrupt the environment. We recommend destroying
these environments first:

vagrant-windows-2012-r2-core (ID: 00d3488f41fa40998bfe16ada2ebfd31)

Are you sure you want to remove this box? [y/N] N

baria@DESKTOP-057K4L5 /c/repos/hub/vtc/linphone-windows-dependencies
$ vagrant destroy windows_2012_r2_core
The machine with the name 'windows_2012_r2_core' was not found configured for
this Vagrant environment.
```

I've googled for an explanation of what a "Vagrant environment" is, and found nothing.  So I don't know how to "destroy an environment".

Even so, I would expect the `destroy` command to acknowledge the existence of my `windows_2012_r2_core` box, given that the `list` and `remove` commands acknowledge its existence.

What is going on here?  How do I cleanly get rid of this box, without warnings or errors?

Answer (score 6):

you can just destroy the VM that is referenced `vagrant destroy 00d3488f41fa40998bfe16ada2ebfd31` will destroy the VM that is using this box and then you'll be able to remove the box.

As @Brandon Davis mention, you can run `vagrant global-status` to see the list of created vagrant VM (from vagrant 1.6+) and you see which VM is 00d3488f41fa40998bfe16ada2ebfd31

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the invalid entries from the list.

`vagrant global-status --prune`

See [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/global-status.html) for more information regarding the command.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: What does `vagrant global-status` show? It looks like there is an environment running that is running this box.